# Application of Fubini's theorem in calculating integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $X = Y = [0,1]$. Define, $f(x,y) = 1 $ if $x=y$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x \neq y$.

I need to determine if $\int_X (\int_Y f_x)$ is equal to $\int_Y (\int_X f_y)$ or not. Here, $f : R^{m+n} \rightarrow R $ and for a give $x \in R^m $ denote $f_x : R^n\rightarrow R$ by $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$ . Similarly for a given $y \in R^n$ denote $f_y : R^m\rightarrow R$ by $f_y(x) = f(x,y)$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Just do the computation. It is very straightforward. Hint, $f$ is zero ae. $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$.

Comment: How..? I don't have a function in $x$ and $y$. It's Just 1 or 0 if $x=y$ or $x \neq y$ respectively.

Comment: Why is that not a function? It is the characteristic function of the diagonal. On any line parallel to an axis (in fact any line not parallel to the diagonal) $f$ is zero everywhere except for the point of intersection. It is easy to compute the integral of such a function.

Comment: It's a function no doubt. Ok.. so you are saying that the points where $x=y$ constitute a set of measure zero?

Comment: Well, yes. In any case, computing $\int_{[0,1]} f(x,y) dx $ is straightforward. What is it that you are having difficulty with?

Comment: So in that case $\int_X (\int_Y f_x)$ = $\int_Y (\int_X f_y)$ = 0 as we can ignore the points of $x=y$ leaving us with only 0

Comment: Yes, the area under a single point on the line is zero, and integrating zero gives zero.

Comment: But my teacher told me that they are not equal.

Comment: There is only one conclusion to draw...

Comment: Incidentally, you have $n=m=1$ above, I'm not sure what the point of the $m,n$ is?